# How to replace tokens in java using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string template containing $variables which needs to be replaced.

String Template: "hi my name is $name.\nI am $age old. I am $sex"

The solution which i tried verifying does not work in the java program. 
http://regexr.com/3dtq1

Further, I referred to https://www.regex101.com/ where i could not check if the pattern works for java. But, while going through one of the tutorials I found that "$   Matches end of line". what's the best way to replace the tokens in the template with the variables?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternCompiler {
    static String text = "hi my name is $name.\nI am $age old. I am $sex";
    static Map<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<String,String>();
    static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\w+");
    static Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        replacements.put("name", "kumar");
        replacements.put("age", "26");
        replacements.put("sex", "male");

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replacement = replacements.get(matcher.group(1));
            if (replacement != null) {
                // matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replacement);
                // see comment 
                matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, "");
                buffer.append(replacement);
            }
        }
        matcher.appendTail(buffer);
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());


    }

}
```

Comment: That should work fine. You've escaped the $ appropriately (\\), so it wont match end of line. Whats the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `matcher.group(1)` but you didn't define any group in the regexp (`(` `)`), so you can use only `group()` for the whole matched string, which is what you want.

Replace line:

```
String replacement = replacements.get(matcher.group(1));
```

With:

```
String replacement = replacements.get(matcher.group().substring(1));
```

Notice the substring, your map contains only words, but matcher will match also `$`, so you need to search in map for "$age".substring(1)" but do replacement on the whole `$age`.

Comment: not quite right - he doesn't want the whole string, just the word after the dollar

Comment: OK, but he needs to replace the text in the string also, so he needs actually both `$age` and `age`. He can get either of those by adding or removing the `$`.

Comment: I tied using the static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\w+"); but it is still not working for me.

Comment: @krzyk ah good point. It does still require brackets to capture though "(\\$\\w+)"?

Comment: @dataEnthusiast Corrected case to take into account your map content, try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the pattern string with

`\\$(\\w+)`

and the variable replacement works. Your current pattern only has group `0` (the entire pattern) but not group `1`. Adding the parenthesis makes the first group the variable name and the replacement will replace the dollar sign and the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has just minor glitches.

```
    static Map<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
    static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\w+\\b"); // \b not really needed

            // As no braces (...) there is no group(1)
            String replacement = replacements.get(matcher.group());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not using the right thing as your key. Change to group(), and change map to '$name' etc:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld {
    static String text = "hi my name is $name.\nI am $age old. I am $sex";
    static Map<String,String> replacements = new HashMap<String,String>();
    static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\w+");
    static Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        replacements.put("$name", "kumar");
        replacements.put("$age", "26");
        replacements.put("$sex", "male");

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replacement = replacements.get(matcher.group());
            System.out.println(replacement);
            if (replacement != null) {
                // matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replacement);
                // see comment 
                matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, "");
                buffer.append(replacement);
            }
        }
        matcher.appendTail(buffer);
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());


    }

}
```